# How to find list of sources[IP] of the redis messages in Redis server

Tags: redis, redis-cli, redis-server

My Redis Server instance handles with multiple publishers. How can I find the list of sources[IP] which published messages in Redis Server in a particular time limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got an answer and posting it for other's reference.

```
redis-cli>client list
```

This above command will give the list of IPs connected to receive/send messages.

Comment: Hi. Is there a way to get the previously connected ones? Like a log for all previous ones or such thing?